# How do I set up mitmproxy between local browser (firefox) and internet for https requests? Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: https, local, ubuntu-20.04, mitmproxy

How do I set up mitmproxy between local browser (firefox) and internet for https requests?
I have been following

```
https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/
```

I have installed mitmproxy on a virtualbox VM running Ubuntu 20.04 with NO UPDATES (I want to run Flash internet game)

```
$ mitmproxy --version
Mitmproxy: 4.0.4
Python:    3.8.2
OpenSSL:   OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
Platform:  Linux-5.11.0-34-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
```

I have installed mitmproxyuser via

```
sudo useradd --create-home mitmproxyuser
sudo -u mitmproxyuser -H bash -c 'cd ~ && pip install --user mitmproxy'
```

Firefox browser `http://mitm.it` would return
`If you can see this, traffic is not passing through mitmproxy.`
but after installing mitmproxy, then `http://mitm.it`, gives `Click to install your mitmproxy certificate`  which I have done.
When I start my game, I see no HTTPS connections happenings.
My script to start up mitmproxy is

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0

sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner mitmproxyuser --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner mitmproxyuser --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo ip6tables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner mitmproxyuser --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo ip6tables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner mitmproxyuser --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

sudo -u mitmproxyuser -H bash -c '/usr/bin/mitmproxy --mode transparent --ssl-insecure --showhost --set block_global=false'
```

(I added `--ssl-insecure` as it complained about mitm CA being wrong)

My game (ss78.evony.com) works fine without mitmproxy running; I can see TCP & SSLV2 traffic via WireShark.
With mitmproxy, my game starts up, does HTTP stuff, displays the login screen, then after login fails with network error. It does HTTPS requests inside the Flash .swf. These do not show in mitmproxy window.

What advice can anyone give me, or what extra information do you require?

#EDIT# updated to include port 443 confirmation screenshot from WireShark.
[image]

Comment: The game seems to be an outdated Flash game. Not sure if Flash respects the proxy settings of the use web browser. May be it checks if internet without proxy is available and if it works it ignores proxy settings. Or it does certificate pinning. I assume you have checked via Wireshark that it does not use a port other than 80/443?

Comment: @Robert Port 443 confirmed. I will update Q to include Port 443 screenshot confirmation. Other points I am unsure about. Maybe I need to set up separate VM as transparent proxy box.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot it looks like the data is not encrypted, so you have a non-TLS/non-HTTP protocol on port 443. I would recommend installing mitmproxy 7 or above, which deals much better with pure TCP traffic.

Comment: When I expand the 'Transport Layer Security' info, it reveals two entries of  '> SSLv2 Record Layer: Encrypted Data > [Version: SSL 2.0 (0x0002)]'. I'll see if I can get mitmproxy v7.0 installed anyway.

Comment: @brewmanz Based on your Wireshark screenshot I would assume that the game uses a fake SSL handshake and then continues to send plain text, an interesting concept. Hopefully the faked handshake does not confuse mitmproxy so that you can view the raw data.